# Custom meta box in custom post type not working

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, theme-development, metabox, warnings

As a wordpress newbie I am having problems in adding custom meta box in my "slider" custom post type which I used in some old wp theme.

I'm getting a warning:

```
Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'new_meta_box' not found or invalid function name in...
```

Here is  my code:

```
/////////////////////////////////////
/* Custom post type slider        */
///////////////////////////////////

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_slider' );

function create_post_type_slider() {
    register_post_type( 'slider',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                 'name' => __( 'Sliders' ),
                 'singular_name' => __( 'slider' ),
                 'search_items' =>  __( 'Search sliders' ),
                 'all_items' => __( 'All sliders' ),
                 'edit_item' => __( 'Edit slider' ),
                 'update_item' => __( 'Update' ),
                 'add_new' => __( 'Add new slider' ),
                 'add_new_item' => __( 'Add new slider' ),
                 'view_item' => __( 'View slider' ),
                 'new_item_name' => __( 'New slider Name' )


            ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title','taxonomies'),
        'has_archive' => false,
        )

    );
    flush_rewrite_rules( false );
}
/* custom post type category */
add_action( 'init', 'create_taxonomie_sliderpos' );
function create_taxonomie_sliderpos() {
 $labels = array(
                 'name' => __( 'Slider Position' ),
                 'singular_name' => __( 'Slider Position' ),
                 'search_items' =>  __( 'Search slider Positions' ),
                 'all_items' => __( 'All Slider Position' ),
                 'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Slider Position' ),
                 'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
                 'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Slider Position' ),
                 'update_item' => __( 'Update slider Position' ),
                 'add_new_item' => __( 'Add' ),
                 'new_item_name' => __( 'New slider Position Name' ),

   );  


register_taxonomy('sliderpos','slider',array(
                     'hierarchical' => true,
                     'labels' => $labels,
                     'show_ui' => true,
                     'show_admin_column' => true,
   ));
 flush_rewrite_rules( false );
} 

//
$prefix = "_ct_";

$slide_info = array (

    "imglnk" => array(
        "type" => "uploadfield",
        "name" => "upload_image",
        "std" => "",
        "width" => "60%",
        "title" => __('Slide image:'),
        "description" => __('Enter the link of the slide image or upload your own image. <strong> Image must be at least 348px height.</strong>')),

        "captitle" => array(
        "type" => "textfield",
        "name" => $prefix."caption_title",
        "std" => "",
        "width" => "60%",
        "title" => __('Caption Title'),
        "description" => __('Enter caption title')),

        "captext" => array(
        "type" => "textarea",
        "name" => $prefix."caption_text",
        "std" => "",
        "title" => __('Caption Text'),
        "description" => __('Enter caption text')),

        "capalign" => array(
        "type" => "align",
        "name" => $prefix."align",
        "std" => "",
        "title" => __('Slide Alignment'),
        "description" => __('')),

        "caplink" => array(
        "type" => "textfield",
        "name" => $prefix."slide_link",
        "std" => "",
        "width" => "60%",
        "title" => __('Slide Link'),
        "description" => __('Enter slide link with http://')),

    );

//Create Metabox on page
function create_meta_box_slider() {    
    global $slide_info;
    add_meta_box( 'new-meta-boxes-slider', __('slider Settings'), 'new_meta_box', 'slider', 'normal', 'high', array('inputs'=>$slide_info) );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'create_meta_box_slider');

//Add $slide_info var to $meta_box_groups array
global $meta_box_groups;
$meta_box_groups[] = $slide_info;
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hey Change Callback function to like this and add_meta_box to add_meta_boxes hook

```
function create_meta_box_slider() {    
    add_meta_box( 'new-meta-boxes-slider', __('slider Settings'), 'new_meta_box', 'slider', 'normal', 'high' );
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'create_meta_box_slider');

function new_meta_box() {
    global $meta_box_groups;
    $meta_box_groups[] = $slide_info;
}
```

I think it work fine

Answer (score 0):

follow the stackexchange  they will explained how you are going to create a meta boxes.

http://bit.ly/1vRnqnV you will get an clear idea about the custom meta box.

Answer (score 0):

add_meta_box should be written on add_meta_boxes hook

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );
function myplugin_add_meta_box()
{
 global $slide_info;
add_meta_box( 'new-meta-boxes-slider', __('slider Settings'), 'new_meta_box', 'slider', 'normal', 'high', array('inputs'=>$slide_info) );
}
```